# Remove text Backgroundcolor in matlab plot

Tags: matlab, text, colors, plot

I have added some text in my plot. But I want to move its background to be as all other background which is gray. I know the following:

```
'Backgroundcolor',[0.7 0.7 0.7]
```

However, [0.7 0.7 0.7] gives color different than the backgroud. How can I make it same ?!

Comment: Just FYI, this might annoying when you export the plot, as the general background is changed to white.

Answer (score 0):

As @FranckDernoncourt said, background colour is changed to white when you export the figure.

However, you can use this to change the colour of the x-axis to be the same as the background colour of the figure:

```
h_fig1 = figure;
x = [1:4]; y = [2:2:8];
plot(x,y);
set(gca,'xcolor',get(h_fig1,'color'))
```

Replace `'xcolor'` with `'ycolor'` to change the colour of the y-axis.

[image: first eg.]

Alternatively, if it is the axis label you want to change the colour of:

```
h_fig1 = figure;
x = [1:4]; y = [2:2:8];
plot(x,y);
h_2 = xlabel('x label');
set(h_2,'color',get(h_fig1,'color'))
```

(Though why you would want to do this, I'm not sure. You might as well just not set the `xlabel` property.)

Or if it is text you added to the plot, this will set the text colour to the background colour of the figure:

```
h_fig1 = figure;
x = [1:4]; y = [2:2:8];
plot(x,y);
h_3 = text(x(2),y(2),'string')
set(h_3,'color',get(h_fig1,'color'))
```

[image: 3rd eg]